# Why am I getting strange behavior for creating several boolean series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame to which I am adding several boolean columns. For each column, I initialize it to False and then set some values to True. If I do this for one and then for another, the first gets reinitialized to all False. For example,

```
In [170]: df['racedif']=False

In [171]: df['racedif'][~ df.newpers]=df.ptdtrace[~ df.newpers]!=df.ptdtrace.groupby(df.personid).apply(pd.Series.shift)[~ df.newpers]

In [172]: df.racedif.sum()
Out[172]: 28

In [173]: df.sexdif.sum()
Out[173]: 0

In [174]: df['sexdif']=False

In [175]: df['sexdif'][~ df.newpers]=df.pesex[~ df.newpers]!=df.pesex.groupby(df.personid).apply(pd.Series.shift)[~ df.newpers]

In [176]: df.sexdif.sum()
Out[176]: 31

In [177]: df.racedif.sum()
Out[177]: 0
```

But if I first initialize them both to False before setting values, this does not happen.

```
In [203]: df['sexdif']=False
     ...: df['racedif']=False
     ...: df['sexdif'][~ df.newpers]=df.pesex[~ df.newpers]!=df.pesex.groupby(df.personid).apply(pd.Series.shift)[~ df.newpers]
     ...: df['racedif'][~ df.newpers]=df.ptdtrace[~ df.newpers]!=df.ptdtrace.groupby(df.personid).apply(pd.Series.shift)[~ df.newpers]
     ...: 

In [204]: df.sexdif.sum()
Out[204]: 31

In [205]: df.racedif.sum()
Out[205]: 28
```

Why is this happening and is this a bug?

***Added a simpler example that does not have the same problem.  Why?***

```
In [255]: df.x=False

In [256]: df.x[df.is456]=df['truth'][df.is456]

In [257]: df.x
Out[257]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: x, dtype: bool

In [258]: df.y=False

In [259]: df.y[df.is456]=df['truth'][df.is456]

In [260]: df.y
Out[260]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: y, dtype: bool

In [261]: df.x
Out[261]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: x, dtype: bool
```

***Non-chained indexing***

```
In [281]: df.loc[:,'sexdif']=False

In [282]: df.sexdif.sum()
Out[282]: 0

In [283]: df.loc[:,'sexdif'][~ df.newpers]=df.pesex[~ df.newpers]!=df.pesex.groupby(df.personid).apply(pd.Series.shift)[~ df.newpers]

In [284]: df.sexdif.sum()
Out[284]: 31

In [285]: df.loc[:,'racedif']=False

In [286]: df.sexdif.sum()
Out[286]: 0
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble following your code here since you do a number of things that are not explained in your question. Can you reproduce the issue with a simpler example? Also, I notice that you set the values in opposite order in your two examples -- is it possible that's the problem? What happens if you initialize them both to False, then set racedif then sexdiff?

Comment: The examples are only to demonstrate the issue (the specific operations aren't important). I initialize a Series to False. Set some values. It works as .sum()!=0.  Initialize another Series to False. Set some values. It works as .sum()!=0.  But now first_series.sum()=0.

Comment: I attempted to construct a simpler example with the same basic features but can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hm. Have you tried changing the order? Notice that in your original code, you only encounter a problem when you set df['sexdif'] after df['racedif']. Can you try it the other way around and see if that fixes it?

Comment: I reversed the order of the first example (initialize, set, initialize, set) and the same problem occurs.  In fact, after I did the second initialization, `df.sexdif.sum()=0` so df.sexdif gets reinitialized when I initialize df.racedif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are chain indexing, see docs here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

bottom line is use

```
df.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value
```

to assign and not

```
df[col_indexer][row_indexer] = value
```

Comment: I understand that the former is better than the latter but unfortunately, that does not solve the problem.  See above.

Comment: it's not that it's better it's the ONLY way; your edit is STILL chain indexing - you need to out the row and column indexers inside the [] you can have only 1 [] (line 283)

Comment: Ah, now I see. When I move my mask into loc, it works.